# Is an emloyee training a challenge for HR or any other manager? How to make it efficient? Are there any specific tools?

Tags: communication, human-resources, company-culture, training

I would like to know what are the most frequently met problems while onboarding and training employees in organizations with 1000+ employees. How to deliver important information to them and make sure they consumed it? What if you want to give them new info daily/weekly?

Thanks

Comment: What info do you need to give them weekly?

Answer (score 2):

The role of HR in this issue would be to ensure employees are informed about all relevant policies, ensure all documents relating to employment are completed out, ensure all company mandated training is completed, ensure the employee has physical access to buildings, etc. **HR does the general stuff applicable to all employees.**

The role of management (including technical leads) is more context-specific around their role. Management would decide on what additional training may need to occur. They would decide what levels of mentoring or tutoring may be required.

HR will often work with management. There is overlap there. HR will struggle without the support of management.

Regarding the sharing of information with employees. My advice is to not go with a discreet system if that can be avoided. If the company uses a Content Management System, you should use that. This is provided that it complies with applicable standards. This means it's in the system the employees use every day. It's way more likely to be shared and seen.

You can't guarantee someone has read something. You can make it more likely by ensuring that information is as terse as possible and relevant.

If information is vital, nothing beats face-to-face. Nothing beats managers buying-into what is said, and discussing it with their direct reports. If you can convince the managers of the importance of an issue, that is how you get a real message to be spread out.

If you are in HR and giving out information to employees on a weekly basis, you're really blunting your ability to communicate important messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be an opinion based answer. I think you can probably brush up the question a bit to get better quality answers. I will post this and change it depending on edits but maintain the generic idea that I think you are trying to ask.
I have just joined a multi-national company with over 7000 employees across the globe with many different jobs. As I sit within a certain department I have been sent the training modules for that department, this means that I am doing online training for a department I work with but completely different to what I do. This is an issue (to a certain extent). This also means that because the previous person that was doing my role left quiet some time before I joined, there is no training specific for my position.

In my opinion one of the biggest issues in larger companies is that you don't get personalized enough material, which is understandable, so it really needs a better local approach from some training team member or ensure that knowledge is being absorbed.

I don't think there is a silver bullet for this, as even if you find what works well for one person in that position it might not work well for the next person.